# sbt constructs wrong path for specific / timestamped snapshot versions

Tags: scala, maven, playframework, sbt, dependency-management

**Background**

I am developing a Play 2.2.3 application; the Play build system uses sbt.

I am using Sonatype Nexus OSS to manage various libraries built and deployed by Maven. At the moment, I am deploying *snapshot versions* of those libraries.  For instance:

```
<groupId>myGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

The Play application depends on snapshot versions of those libraries.

**Intention**

In the Play project, I want to use a *specific* (thus, "timestamped") snapshot version of a dependency -- say `0.1-20140509.053703-1` -- instead of the latest one as specified by `0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

**Issue**

While the latter works perfectly well, sbt seems to be unable to resolve the specific version. At least sbt constructs the URL pointing to that specific version faultily: The name of the directory that contains the artifact ends with the actual timestamp instead of string `SNAPSHOT`.

**Example**

I created a new Play application and added the following dependency in file `build.sbt`: `libraryDependencies += "myGroup" % "myArtifact" % "0.1-20140509.053703-1"`

When resolving that dependency, sbt constructs URLs ending with `myGroup/myArtifact/0.1-20140509.053703-1/myArtifact-0.1-20140509.053703-1.pom`.

Note that the 3rd path component is `0.1-20140509.053703-1`. Thus, the directory containing artifact `myArtifact` incorrectly contains the timestamp as well.

The *correct* directory name would be `0.1-SNAPSHOT`; thus, using `SNAPSHOT` instead of the actual timestamp. The complete correct URL would thus end with `myGroup/myArtifact/0.1-SNAPSHOT/myArtifact-0.1-20140509.053703-1.pom`.

Referring to the latest snapshot version instead by using dependency entry `libraryDependencies += "myGroup" % "myArtifact" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT"` works. The URLs end with `0.1-SNAPSHOT/myArtifact-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom`.

**Question**

How could I persuade sbt to download a specific snapshot version?

Comment: I created [Issue #1325](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1325) in the sbt GitHub project.

Comment: This seems to be caused by Ivy. I created [IVY-1476](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1476) as I was not able to find an existing Ivy issue that would handle this problem.

Comment: Any updates on this issue?